# threading.local from a different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, heroku

I'm trying to make a threaded cgi webserver similar to [this](https://pymotw.com/2/BaseHTTPServer/index.html#threading-and-forking); however, I'm stuck on how to set local data in the handler *for a different thread*.  Is it possible to set `threading.local` data, such as a dict, for a thread other than the handler.  To be more specific I want to have the request parameters, headers, etc available from a cgi file that was started with `subprocess.run`.  The bottom of the `do_GET` in [this file on github](https://github.com/jath03/server/blob/heroku/handler.py) is what I use now, but that can only serve one client at a time. I want to replace this part because I want multiple connections/threads at once, and I need different data in each connection/thread.

Is there a way to edit/set `threading.local` data **from a different thread.**  Or if there is a better way to achieve what I am trying, please let me know.  If you know that this is definently impossible, say so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what test code you have, and knowing what you've tried so far, I can't tell you exactly what you need to succeed. That said, I can tell you that trying to edit information in a threading.local() object from another thread is not the cleanest path to take.

Generally, the best way to send calls to other threads is through threading.Event() objects. Usually, a thread listens to an Event() object and does an action based on that. In this case, I could see having a handler set an event in the case of a GET request.

Then, in the thread that is writing the cgi file, have a function that, when the Event() object is set, records the data you need and unsets the Event() object.

So, in pseudo-code:

```
import threading

evt = threading.Event()

def noteTaker(evt):
  while True:
    if evt.wait(): 
      modifyDataYouNeed()
      f.open()
      f.write()
      f.close()
      evt.clear()

def do_GET(evt):
  print "so, a query hit your webserver"
  evt.set()
  print "and noteTaker was just called"
```

So, while I couldn't answer your question directly, I hope this helps some on how threads communicate and will help you infer what you need :)

threading information (as I'm sure you've read already, but for the sake of diligence) is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

Comment: Hmm... haven't looked into events much.  Can an event contain data such as a dictionary?

Comment: And to clarify there isn't a thread _writing_ to a cgi file, the thread is writing to a `.dat` file that is read by the cgi file.

Comment: That is the part I am trying to replace with `threading.local` because I want different data depending on the thread.